# Coding in R - how to do rolling window without a for-loop? For-loop too slow

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I understand for-loops are slow in R, and the suite of apply() functions are designed to be used instead (in many cases).

However, I can't figure out how to use those functions in my situation, and advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have a list/vector of values (let's say length=10,000) and at every point, starting at the 21st value, I need to take the standard deviation of the trailing 20 values. So at 21st, I take SD of 1st-21st . At 22nd value, I take SD(2:22) and so on.

So you see I have a rolling window where I need to take the SD() of the previous 20 indices. Is there any way to accomplish this faster, without a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question.

The zoo package has a function called "rollapply" which does exactly that: uses apply() on a rolling window basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

# dummy vector
c <- 50
x <- sample(1:100, c, replace=T)

# parameter
y <- 20               # length of each vector
z <- length(x) - y    # final starting index

# benchmark
xx <-
microbenchmark(lapply = {a <- lapply( 1:z, \(i) sd(x[i:(i+y)]) )}
               , loop = {
                            b <- vector("list", z)
                            for (i in 1:z)
                            {
                              b[[i]] <- sd(x[i:(i+y)])
                              }
                           }
               , times = 30
               )

# plot
autoplot(xx) +
  ggtitle(paste('vector of size', c))
```

[image: vector of size 50]
[image: vector of size 10000]

It would appear while `lapply` has the speed advantage of a smaller vector, a loop should be used with longer vectors.

I would maintain, however, loops are not slow per se as long as they are not applied incorrectly (iterating over rows).

Comment: A problem with your loop implementation is that it grows the loop with each step.  Pre-allocating the final length helps a lot.  `lapply()` is still better, but not 10 times better.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for your comment. How does the current loop set up grow with each step?

Comment: Setting `b <- list()` makes it length 0.  Each time you set `b[[i]] <- value` it grows by one.  You can initialize using `b <- vector("list", z)` to initialize it to length `z`.

Comment: @user2554330 Appreciate your guide. Updated my code above. Re-tested and found loop had a small advantage with a large vector (1e5). Let me know what u think